# IDE Eclipse (e Java) utilizando mais memória que o alocado

Tags: java, eclipse

Primeiramente, gostaria de dizer que ainda sou iniciante em Java, posso estar interpretando alguma informação de maneira errada.

Recentemente, instalei a IDE Eclipse (Versão 03/2022) e comecei a aprender como usá-la. Tudo estava indo bem, o único problema é que o programa começou a consumir uma quantidade absurda de memória RAM, tornando a utilização de qualquer outro programa paralelo a ele inviável. Pesquisando, descobri que a IDE possui um arquivo .ini onde é possível passar argumentos para a execução do código, tornando possível estabelecer um limite para o uso da memória. Os argumentos são:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vm
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
```

Entretanto, ao executar novamente o programa com os argumentos, nada muda. Ele continua a consumir a mesma quantidade exorbitante de memória (já chegou a consumir 2GB). Gostaria muito de utilizar essa IDE mas desta forma simplesmente não será possível, e tenho certeza que há algum meio de reduzir esse uso de memória. Alguém pode me ajudar a descobrir o erro do programa? Estou fazendo algo de errado?

Answer (score -2):

Podes crer que o consumo de exagerado de memória por parte de software java, é comum.Nunca tive tanta paciência para estabelecer um limite de memória a ser usada pela IDE (Net Beans, que também é um problema).  Mas este pelo menos traz um recurso que permite, forçar o Garbage collector que por sua vez libera a memória ocupara por variáveis da IDE, já não referenciadas. Basta dar um clique naquele recurso. Dá uma olhada ma imagem.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Realmente, já ouvi falar muito que o alto consumo de memória por parte do Java é comum. Forçar o Garbage Collector pode ser uma solução, mas essa imagem que você anexou é do Net Beans. Você conhece uma função parecida para o Eclipse?

Comment: Desculpa-me pela demora. Solução para a IDE eclipse, eu não conheço. Portanto, eu te indiquei a IDE Net Beans, que também uso e tem dado jeito. Estou criando um projeto em Java quando já estava bem avançado me apercebi que o Java tem esse problema (consumo exagerado de memória). foi um grande choque para mim, mas estou procurando um jeito de lidar com isso. caso algum dia encontres alguma solução para implementar em algum projeto, dá-me um sinal.

Comment: Certo. Vou continuar procurando bastante pois estou tendo problemas em diversos projetos e programas por causa disso. Vou deixar a pergunta aberta enquanto isso para que mais pessoas possam ajudar com uma solução.